# Laravel where query using model's boolean function

Tags: laravel

I have a simple model function that returns either true or false, based on some logic that uses a number of columns of the model. So I can't just say `where('quantity', '>', 10)` or suchlike.

How would I create a where clause that can use this function? I have created a stripped back example of code that might appear in my model's file:

```
public function scopeWhereBoxNeeded($query)
{
    return $query->where(/* - - - - something here! - - - - */);
}

public function boxNeeded()
{
    
    if( $this->packets * $this->quantity > 21) // Potentially much more complex logic here
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
    
}
```

Now, in my controller I'd like to say `Products::whereBoxNeeded()->get()`. How do I do it?

**Sidenote**

At present I am returning all the models that match a broader query, then doing

```
$products = $products->filter(function($product)
{
    return $product->boxNeeded();
});
```

But this is breaking the pagination, as I use `{{ $products->links() }}` in the view, and I think after filtering the query this is removed.

#### Edit

The actual query I am doing is much more complicated:

```
public function boxNeeded()
{
    $now = Config::get('next_cut_off')->copy();
    $now->subMonths($this->month_joined);
    if(($now->month + 12 + $this->subscription_frequency) % $this->subscription_frequency == 0)
         return true;
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom where statement like:

```php
public function scopeWhereBoxNeeded($query)
{
    return $query->whereRaw('(quantity * packets) > 10');
}
```

Comment: I really need it to work via a function, as I'll be using a much more complicated query (see edit). My question is how can I use the result of a function that returns true / false in a where statement

Comment: As I understood you want to use a Php logic inside a Sql statement, I think the best way is to include the logic inside the sql statement.
The result of your function depends on Sql data which is not present.